# How to access user defined data types declared in .so (shared libraries) in c

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, .so

I have some external .so file. I am writing a program to call some of the API's of the .so library.

I have used dlopen and dlsym as below

```
void *handle = dlopen ("/new_project/lib/Test_external.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void (*fptr)(char *);
fptr = dlsym((void *) handle, "func1");
(fptr)("module_name");
```

I was able to call func1(char *)

However I am not sure how to call the api which requires a object of the structure that is defined in the .so file. For example

```
func2(structure1 obj1);
```

Even tried to use dlopen using RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL. Nothing worked.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: In general, use header files to share common declarations.

Comment: When i try to include the header files of .so which has global declarations, I see the error "No such file or directory"

Comment: Then you might want to ask about *that* instead.

Comment: For most practical purposes, you can't invent types on the fly. If a set of functions works with opaque types (pointers to structures where the type is not known at compile time), you can write code to use the functions — as long as you don't have to allocate space for a structure (the library does that for you), and as long as you never need to access a member of the structure directly (that's what makes the type opaque). If the library provides functions that can provide access to members of a structure in terms of types known a compile time, you can use it. If not, it is (at best) hard!

Comment: If you have `libfoo.so` then you also should have a `foo.h`. Otherwise your sysadmin for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have runtime-dynamic types. Assuming you know what library you will be loading at the time you write/build your program, or even just know what types it uses in its public interfaces, you include the appropriate headers to declare those types.

If you don't know that, but the data of dynamic type is only passed by reference (e.g. with `void *` pointers), then if the library provides some sort of description of the type to you at runtime (e.g. a table of member, their types, and their offsets) then you can `malloc` storage for such an object and build it dynamically using that information and pass it to the library.

If the library needs dynamic types passed by value, then you are dealing with a **foreign function interface** outside the scope of what you can do in C with `dlopen` alone, and you need a FFI implmentation supporting the C implementations you care about, such as `libffi`, which can construct and make calls dynamically.